# An action in a controller without a view (for AJAX)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm am trying to make an ajax request in rails. What I want to do is call an action in the controller from my javascript without having to create an a view page for it. For example

```
class BooksContoller < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json, :xml

  def myaction
    respond_to do |format|
     format.js { # do stuff  }
    end
  end

end
```

In the routes.rb file I added the following

```
match '/books/myaction' => 'books#myaction'
```

here's the ajax call that I am making

```
$.ajax(
{
  type: "GET", url: "/books/myaction.js",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data); 
  } 
});
```

Rails is complaining about not finding the view

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}
```

Obviously if I create a corresponding myaction.html.haml file it's happy and everything works. However I don't wanna create a view for this action as this will only be used for ajax requests. Is there a way to make ajax calls to a custom action without creating a view for it?

Comment: Is it because you are responding to :json but using .js as the extension?

Comment: @s-c were you able to find a solution for this? I'm facing exact same problem in Rails 3.2.14. All I want is an action in one of my controllers that returns a json string that I then pass on to jqplot to draw a graph. No views involved. 

I've even tried using "render :text => data, :content_type => 'application/json'". But still get the same error.

Comment: Please ignore. I was able to fix my error. I'm using CanCan for authorization / access control and after looking closely at the stack trace, the "Actionview::MissingTemplate" was being raised after cancan's AccessDenied check kicks in. If I login and access my newly created action, everything works. I've also added my new action as an exception to CanCan's load_and_authorize_resource.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put `render :json => {:example => :object}` at the end. For example:

```
def myaction
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
      # do stuff
      render :json => {:result => :of_stuff}
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, if you know you'll only use this for AJAX requests, then you can skip the respond_to completely (this will allow you to call the URI with or without `.js`):

```
def myaction
  render :json => {:result => :of_stuff}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have respond_to :html, and my bet is that your javascript doesn't set "Accept: application/json". Remove the respond_to both from the class level as well as from the method.